# Can i modify a get method of an entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

To customize a GetName method of my entity User, can I do this directly in mu entity or I have to go through a custom method in my repository?

I just want to return the name preceded by a dash...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to create another method which will return

```
# Name.php

    public function getDashedName()
    {
        return '- ' . $this->getName();
    }
```

If you can't, then yes, you have to modify the `getName()` function in your entity. The repository is only here to manipulate queries for your object.